# installing clipgrab update

Tags: 11.04

ClipGrab released an update, which I am unable to update, I've downloaded the package but it's not deb and I'm having issues after extracting the file, not sure how to install it!
has anyone successfully updated Clipgrab 3.1.0.2 using the source code? I'm so confused!

http://clipgrab.de/en#linux

`ricochet@ricochet-Satellite-L305:~$ cd ~/Downloads` 
`ricochet@ricochet-Satellite-L305:~/Downloads$ chmod +x clipgrab-3.1.0.2-1` 
`chmod: cannot access clipgrab-3.1.0.2-1': No such file or directory` 
`ricochet@ricochet-Satellite-L305:~/Downloads$`

```
    drwx--x--x 2 ricochet ricochet      4096 2011-08-05 10:00 clipgrab-3.1.0.2
    -rw-r--r-- 1 ricochet ricochet    148002 2011-08-15 18:14 clipgrab-3.1.0.2.tar.bz2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you downloaded the package from [this website](http://clipgrab.de/en#linux)?
Make sure you download the package clipgrab-3.1.0.2.bz2 - you can find this under the option "Show All Available Options"

It should open in Archive Manager.  Extract it to your Downloads folder.

Then in a terminal:

```
cd ~/Downloads
chmod +x clipgrab-3.1.0.2
```

Then you can start it:

```
./clipgrab-3.1.0.2
```

...

or you could just add the current [clipgrab PPA](https://launchpad.net/~clipgrab-team/+archive/ppa/+packages)

and install via

```
sudo apt-get install clipgrab
```

If you have the PPA already installed, then run the Update Manager to get the latest version.

As an aside - remember, sometimes you may have to wait a few days for the maintainers of the PPA to update with the latest version.

Comment: hmm, yep that is the correct website I downloaded from. here's what I get when I enter the command:

`ricochet@ricochet-Satellite-L305:~$ cd ~/Downloads`

`ricochet@ricochet-Satellite-L305:~/Downloads$ chmod +x clipgrab-3.1.0.2-1`

`chmod: cannot access clipgrab-3.1.0.2-1': No such file or directory`

`ricochet@ricochet-Satellite-L305:~/Downloads$`

the file is there though...

Comment: yep I extracted the file.

Comment: what was the result of `ls -l` ?

Comment: the result of `ls -l` is in the question now. (sorry I'm a noob, but I appreciate the help very much!)

Comment: I dont think you are actually in the Downloads folder - see my answer - `cd ~/Downloads` then `ls -l` - you can copy and paste this text.  Its a lowercase "L" for `ls` and lowercase "L" for `-l`

Comment: @ricochet let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1081/discussion-between-fossfreedom-and-ricochet)

Comment: ahh, yes I will do that and put the results in the answer

Comment: I'm trying to get into chat but I'm being told to log in, although I am already, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: ok - not sure what is wrong with the chat-room.  You have downloaded the .tar.bz2 file.  Try to download the binary file from the website - its under the "Show all available options" hyperlink.

Comment: I'm available in chat now!